# What is the Esperanto work for "buzz"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Google Translate gives me "zumado" to mean buzzing. I am specifically looking for the word in the context of marketing buzz:

> They created a fantastic *buzz* around their product launch during their marketing campaign

Is zumado correct in a generic sense? If so, does it also apply in this context as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laŭ mi `zumado`, en tiu kunteksto, bonas ĉar tiu radiko havas plurajn signifojn kaj [unu el ili](https://vortaro.net/#zumi_kd) estas `konfuza bruo`, kiun povus estigi homoj, kaj kiu ne rilatas "z" sonon, ĝi temas pri neklara bruo voĉa.

Ekzemplo (el la vortaro PIV):

- la senĉesa zumado de la virinaj langoj ĉirkaŭ la akuŝintino

Notu ke tiu zumado estas tamen, por la partoprenantoj, konversacio pri iu specifa temo. El ekstere ĝi aspektas zumade ĉar oni ne povas disigi la sonojn.

Alia ekzemplo, Zamenhofa ĉi foje:

- [ĝi] aŭdis kantadon kaj muzikon, la susuradon kaj zumadon de multe da homoj

Ekzakte tiun signifon oni celas en marketika kuntektsto. La multa, daŭra kaj ne nepre klara priparolado de produkto, farita de amaso da personoj, retejoj, ĵurnaloj, ktp.

Comment: I had to use Google Translate, so forgive me please for poor phrasing, etc, but: "Dankon pro la konsilo. Mi emas konsenti!"

Comment: Note that in marketing a term "buzz word" is also used. In that meaning the correct translation is [_frapvorto_](https://vortaro.net/#frapvorto_kd).

Answer (score 1):

> Is zumado correct in a generic sense?

No, *zum·ad·o* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#zumado_kd); from the verb [*zum·i*](https://vortaro.net/#zumi_kd), which probably derives from the German verb [*summen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summen#Verb))  is specifically about various continuous "z"-**sounds** (buzzing, humming, etc.) and similar **noises** (e.g. how one perceives the mix of multiple concurrent discussions in a noisy bar), while the English "buzz" can be used in either a literal sense (also referring to such sounds) **or** in a **metaphorical** sense.

> If so, does it also apply in this context as well?

Probably not, as a marketing "buzz" is almost surely a "buzz" in the metaphorical sense. While it might be "loud" and "noisy", it could be so in a literal or metaphorical sense and in either case probably isn't limited to "z" sounds.

While many Esperanto words can (at least colloquially) be used metaphorically even when such a meaning isn't listed in the dicitonaries, this always risks being misunderstood, if the metaphor isn't one either universal or shared by many popular languages or can for other reasons be readily and unambiguously be understood. I doubt *zumado* would fall in one of these categories.

Comment: I am intrigued by this answer and I appreciate the depth you have gone to in providing it. My main thought is that I would say a marketing 'buzz' is a literal noise rather than metaphorical though. It's just hard to detect because it is happening over a wider geographical area than an immediate vicinity. Take when Tesla launched a car into space, people were talking about it and this was a literal noise of sorts. For now I will accept the answer from @eduardo-trápani but I'd be happy to hear more if offered. I might be misunderstanding something due to not understanding nuances of language